# Selecting data for a region from Google Earth Engine

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I am using `Python` to work with Google Earth Engine. I would like to extract some data for Paris.

I got the shapefile of Paris and I extracted its boundary as shown below:

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import pylab as plt

gdf = gpd.read_file('drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/shapefiles/France/COMMUNE-shp/')     ## Paris metro area
gdf = gdf.to_crs(epsg=4326)

def returnCityBoundary(gdf):
  ## from shapefile it returns city boundary as a rectangle in different format
  #### polygon_geom: shapely polygon
  #### polygon: geopandas dataframe
  #### geometry: Earth Engine polygon
  bounds = gdf.total_bounds
  lon_point_list = [bounds[0], bounds[0], bounds[2], bounds[2]]
  lat_point_list = [bounds[1], bounds[3], bounds[3], bounds[1]]
  polygon_geom = Polygon(zip(lon_point_list, lat_point_list))
  crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
  polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=crs, geometry=[polygon_geom]) 
  geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
          [[[bounds[0], bounds[1]],
            [bounds[0], bounds[3]],
            [bounds[2], bounds[3]],
            [bounds[2], bounds[1]]]])
  return polygon_geom, polygon, geometry

polygon, gdf_polygon, geometry = returnCityBoundary(gdf)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
gdf_polygon.boundary.plot(ax=ax, color='red')
gdf.boundary.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

Now I would like to extract some images in this boundary. This is what I am doing but it does not work.

```
cover = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A2').filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-05-01'))\
  .select('LST_Day_1km')\
  .filterBounds(geometry)
```

Comment: what do these multiple small polygons represent?

Comment: @YogeshChavan this is the `shapefile` of Paris metropolitan area. I use it to get the bounding box around it (the red rectangle).

Comment: can you elaborate, what does not work ? do you get an error ?

Comment: @PierrickRambaud I do not get an error but I get the data for the entire world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments, the output you are getting is expected. MODIS images on the Google Earth Engine do not come in granules, therefore, your image collection will contain single images of the entire world regardless of filtering by location using `.filterBounds`. Rather, you will have to `.clip` each image to `geometry` to get your desired output:

```
cover_clipped = cover.map(lambda image : image.clip(geometry))
```